# Getting Data from php through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am a novice to PHP, trying to learn.

I have my php file present in **www** folder in the WAMP server.

```
<?php

    echo 'Hi';
?>
```

This can be run if I go `http://127.0.0.1/testRequestParameter.php` from my Browser, it prints **Hi**

So now I created an HTML page(**not present in the same directory**)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jsLibrary/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getTestDataFromAjax()
    {
    var url =   'http://127.0.0.1/testRequestParameter.php';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        },
        async:false
      });

    }
</script>

    <input type="submit"  name="Button" onclick="javascript:getTestDataFromAjax(); return false;" />
</body>
</html>
```

And when I try to call that php through AJAX, the response is blank.

May be it I am missing something, any help will be appreciated.

Finding1: In my firebug it is showing, `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1/testRequestParameter.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Any setting which I need to change?

Comment: can you paste the whole HTML page pls?

Comment: maybe you should change `url` into `"http://127.0.0.1/testRequestParameter.php"`

Comment: @Alex: Have updated that, kindly check

Comment: @Jonan: Have tried with that too :(

Comment: Does the javascript run when you press the button? Use the debugger to watch it execute and see what is returned in the data variable.

Comment: I believe you should include jquery library adding
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
in the head section

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes Sir, I have checked that in firebug, the response is blank request is constructed properly

Comment: So where does the html/php file live that you use to test the call to the javascript?

Comment: @RiggsFolly My php file is in the WAMP directory inside the "www" folder, but the index file is on desktop

Comment: Put them both in the wamp folder, better in a subfolder of `\wamp\www\` like `\wamp\www\project1`. You should never put anything in the `\wamp\www` folder as you will eventually overwrite the `index.php` in there which is the wamp homepage script.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I can only put the php file in the WAMP folder, 
I want the other anywhere but not inside the WAMP directory, 

This is a local set up, which I need to do for two different domains

Comment: Using the dataType of jsonp in your Ajax should allow you to get the information from a cross origin point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scenario

I tested your script using EasyPHP: I created into `http://localhost/script/test/` the file *content.php*

```
<?php
echo 'Hi!';
?>
```

Then, I added to my desktop *index.php*:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getTestDataFromAjax()
    {
    var url =   'http://localhost/script/test/content.php';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        },
        async:false
      });

    }
</script>

    <input type="submit"  name="Button" onclick="javascript:getTestDataFromAjax(); return false;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I launched *index.php* and clicked on the button, which returned an error when clicked:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/script/test/content.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

### Solution

So, I edited my *content.php* like this:

```
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
echo 'Hi!';
?>
```

And it's now working

Comment: I think you kept both the file in the same directory, My php file is in the WAMP directory inside the "www" folder, but the index file is on desktop

Comment: You're right; I'm going to test your scenario and edit my answer

Comment: That will be very nice of you :)

Comment: By the way, I noticed in my firebug, I got this:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1/testRequestParameter.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed about it in chrome console too, the problem was in headers- check my edited answer :)

Comment: That is great, Let me check :)